# Semantic-release: How to downgrade the major version that is already published to artifactory?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, git-commit, semantic-release

Say, the previous release was done by squashing the commits. And including `BREAKING CHANGE` text at the end of the squashed commit message which released version `2.0.0`.

thereafter, a new patch release was done which published version `2.0.1`.

After this, a `feature` was pushed wherein we didn't decide to squash the messages so that semantic-release could decide which version number to bump it to using the commit message.
Technically it should have bumped it to `2.1.1`

Instead it bumped it to `3.0.0` by considering all the skipped(squashed) commit messages meanwhile and published it to artifactory.

Now how can I downgrade my version to let's say back to `2.x.x`? either manually or using semantic-release.